# Rollup / recursive addition SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query `with rollup` that outputs data like (the query is a little busy, but I can post if necessary)

```
range    subCounts    Counts    percent
1-9      3            100       3.0
10-19    13           100       13.0
20-29    30           100       33.0
30-39    74           100       74.0
NULL     100          100       100.0
```

How is it possible to keep a running summation total of `percent`?  Say I need to find the bottom 15 percentile, in this case `3+13=16` so I would like for the last row to be returned read

```
range    subCounts    counts    percent
10-19    13           100       13.0
```

**EDIT1:** here the query

```
select '$'+cast(+bin*10000 + ' ' as varchar(10)) + '-' + cast(bin*10000+9999 as varchar(10)) as bins, 
    count(*) as numbers,
    (select count(distinct patient.patientid) from patient 
    inner join tblclaims on patient.patientid = tblclaims.patientid
    and patient.admissiondate = tblclaims.admissiondate
    and patient.dischargedate = tblclaims.dischargedate
    inner join tblhospitals on tblhospitals.hospitalnpi = patient.hospitalnpi
    where (tblhospitals.hospitalname = 'X') 
    ) as Totals
    , round(100*count(*)/cast((select count(distinct patient.patientid) from patient 
    inner join tblclaims on patient.patientid = tblclaims.patientid
    and patient.admissiondate = tblclaims.admissiondate
    and patient.dischargedate = tblclaims.dischargedate
    inner join tblhospitals on tblhospitals.hospitalnpi = patient.hospitalnpi
    where (tblhospitals.hospitalname = 'X')) as float),2) as binsPercent


from
(

select tblclaims.patientid, sum(claimsmedicarepaid) as TotalCosts, 
    cast(sum(claimsmedicarePaid)/10000 as int) as bin
    from tblclaims inner join patient on patient.patientid = tblclaims.patientid
    and patient.admissiondate = tblclaims.admissiondate 
    and patient.dischargedate = tblclaims.dischargedate
    inner join tblhospitals on patient.hospitalnpi = tblhospitals.hospitalnpi
    where tblhospitals.hospitalname = 'X'
    group by tblclaims.patientid
)   as t 
group by bin with rollup
```

Comment: edited post to include query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so for whomever might use this for reference I figured out what I needed to do.

I added `row_number() over(bin) as rownum` to the query and saved all of this as a view.

Then I used

```
SELECT *,
          SUM(t2.binspercent) AS SUM
FROM t t1
INNER JOIN t t2 ON t1.rownum >= t2.rownum
GROUP BY t1.rownum,
         t1.bins, t1.numbers, t1.uktotal, t1.binspercent
ORDER BY t1.rownum
```

by joining t1.rownum >=t2.rownum you can get the rolling count sort of thing.

Comment: I've seen an article on another way to do it, I just can't remember where exactly, sorry

Comment: I'm trying to get it done without using a view, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what i was looking for, but it's on the same track:
http://blog.tallan.com/2011/12/08/sql-server-2012-windowing-functions-part-1-of-2-running-and-sliding-aggregates/ and http://blog.tallan.com/2011/12/19/sql-server-2012-windowing-functions-part-2-of-2-new-analytic-functions/ - check out PERCENT_RANK
CUME_DIST
PERCENTILE_CONT
PERCENTILE_DISC

Sorry for the lame answer